# RDD transform into Spark

Tags: matrix, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have the next RDD, which looks like :

```
((0,1), 2)
((0,2), 3)
((1,1), 3)
```

I'm looking currently for some method, which convert the given RDD to the form:

```
([0, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 0])
```

In the other words, the method creates a RDD of lists according the key values in the initial RDD. If some value is not available, then the methods put just 0 on this place.

I coded someself the next two methods, which I use for the executable solution.

```
def matrixForm(rdd):
        rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda ((x,y),k): (x,y,k))
        rdd3 = rdd2.map(lambda (i,j,e): (j, (i,e))).groupByKey().sortByKey()
        rdd4 = rdd3.map(lambda (i, x): sorted(list(x), cmp=lambda (i1,e1),(i2,e2) : cmp(i1, i2)))
        rdd5 = rdd4.map(lambda x: map(lambda (i, y): y , x))
        rdd6 = rdd5.map(lambda x: list(x))
        rdd7 = rddTranspose(rdd6)
        return rdd7

def rddTranspose(rdd):
        rddT1 = rdd.zipWithIndex().flatMap(lambda (x,i): [(i,j,e) for (j,e) in enumerate(x)])
        rddT2 = rddT1.map(lambda (i,j,e): (j, (i,e))).groupByKey().sortByKey()
        rddT3 = rddT2.map(lambda (i, x): sorted(list(x), cmp=lambda (i1,e1),(i2,e2) : cmp(i1, i2)))
        rddT4 = rddT3.map(lambda x: map(lambda (i, y): y , x))
        return rddT4.map(lambda x: list(x))
```

This way is working, but seems to be not efficient. If somebody has a time and wish to discuss and improve my solution, please participate in the discussion. Thank you in advance.

PS The second example for input and output

```
((0,0), 1)
((1,1), 1)
((2,2), 1)
((3,3), 1)

([1,0,0,0]
 [0,1,0,0]
 [0,0,1,0]
 [0,0,0,1])
```

The highest index of id1 is a number of lists, the highest index of id2 is a length of every unique list

Comment: let me clarify your question a bit. You have an rdd of the form `RDD[((id1, id2), value)]`. You want to transform it into the form `RDD[list(id1, id2, value)]`. However, some entries in the rdd does not have a value. That is, there exist an element in the rdd that looks like this: `((someId1, someId2), " ")`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, but the list should have only values (without keys). For example, I have the first id1 twice 0 and related id2 is one time 1 and another time 2 (see my example). I want to create a list of all values for id1 = 0 in the order by id2: `[((0,0), 0), ((0,1), 2), ((0,2), 3)] -> [0,2,3]` as a python list. For every index pair in my initial RDD. The Keys for me are the positions in the list

Comment: can you give an example initial rdd with more entries and also the expected rdd output?

Comment: This is the first example above. My initial RDD has 3 lines with keys and values. I want create two lists according the keys values. It means, the quantity of different values for id1 is equal to the number of the lists in the new RDD, the second id2 is a position of the value in the list.

Comment: Got one more example, do hope now is much clearer

Comment: I see. you want to create a dense matrix out of a sparse matrix representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def toRow(n, lst):
    row = [0] * n
    for (index, val) in lst:
        row[index] = val
    return row

def toDense(rdd):
    n = rdd.map(lambda ((i, j), k): j).max() + 1
    rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda ((i,j), k): (i, (j,k)))
    rdd2 = rdd1.groupByKey().sortByKey().map(lambda x: list(x[1]))
    return rdd2.map(lambda lst: toRow(n, lst))
```

then take a look:

```
toDense(rdd).take(2)
```

Comment: @Guforu, with the dataset that you have, is it possible to obtain `[0,0,0,0]` in the final answer? In my code, I did not include that case but I can change the code to reflect that.

Comment: This is actually not possible, I want to prevent this option... Thank you again, your solution has improved my time perfomance